# How to check the type of database Heroku is using?

Tags: heroku

I just updated database plans on Heroku from hobby-dev to standard-0. How can I check to make sure that the standard-0 postgres database is the one being used?

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of [Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) (actually a few versions of Toolbelt ago) you can run:

```
heroku addons -a <your app name>
```

The CLI will give you information regarding the PG addon from Heroku, including level and price.

You could also visit your app's dashboard at [dashboard.heroku.com](http://dashboard.heroku.com), click on your app and go to the resources tab.